# Limit of $f(x,y) = xy \log(x^2+y^2)$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find whether $\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} f(x,y) = xy \log(x^2+y^2)$ exists? I have tried several things but nothing fruitful so far, does anyone have a hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By polar coordinates

$$\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} xy \log(x^2+y^2)=\lim_{r\to0^+}2r^2\cos \theta\sin\theta \log r= 0$$

indeed for $t\to 0^+$

$$t\log t \to 0$$

Comment: i made a small edit, I hope you dont mind

Comment: @qbert That's a good editing! Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate a bit further though? I don't follow this.

Comment: you can set $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ bybpolar coordinates to reduce the limit to a standard one, what step is not clear to you?